# Error when updating Angular app from version 10.2 to 11.0

Tags: angular

I'm trying to update my Angular project. I have done this already multiple times in the past and it worked well. But from version 10.2 to 11.0 I get this error right when running the first update command from the guide (update.angular.io):

```
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11
```

And this is the error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.14" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=0.900.0" from ngx-build-plus@10.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-build-plus
npm ERR!     dev ngx-build-plus@"^10.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.14" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.14" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/michael/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Has anyone experienced this error and knows how to handle it? I'm unfortunately a bit helpless.

Comment: Did you try with the `--force` option?

Comment: @GaëlJ I was not so eager to try it with force. I came across 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps' and that helped me, but I think something is still somewhat faulty in my configuration.

Answer (score 4):

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps` right after the posted error message was what did the trick. It helped me to continue my Angular update from 10.2 to 11, and then to 12.

The project has no problems afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that the code editor was open.

On closing the editor and running `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli` angular successfully updated

---

Otherwise , try below :

```
* Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
* npm cache clean --force
* npm i --force
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it did not resolve the problem. 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps' helpled me, but something is still somewhat faulty in my configuration I guess.